# Hide elements for CSS selector rules

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to build an HTML page with accordion-style functionality. First off, I have this simple CSS selector, stating "if the H1 is right after another H1, make the background red".

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1 + h1 
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Then some plain HTML:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Second</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Third</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
```

All the H1s look like they should, none have a red background, because they're preceeded by a P tag.

For this:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<h1>Second</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Third</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
```

The second H1 has a red background, because the P tag between the it and previous H1 is removed. Very nice.

Now, what I *actually* want to do is to programmatically hide the "content" below the H1s and then I would like to see the red-rule kick in. Like this:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Second</h1>
<p style="display: none">Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Third</h1>
<p>Hello world...</p>
```

But since the P tag is still there, the CSS rule doesn't apply for the third H1, and there's no red background.

**Question: Is there a way to apply something using JavaScript to the P tags that will cause them to (temporarily) ignored by the CSS rule??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it came to me as I was writing the question. So, for future reference, here's my own solution:

Add a second rule for the red background, simply stating "H1 after H1 OR H1 following any tag with a 'hidden' class set":

```
h1 + h1, .hidden + h1
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

And a simple hide-class:

```
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

Then I can simply add a "hidden" class to the content P tags:

```
<h1>First</h1>
<p>Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Second</h1>
<p class="hidden xxx">Blah, blah...</p>
<h1>Third</h1>
<p>Hello world...</p>
```

Viola, the third H1 is red. :) AND I can apply any other classes (the "xxx") I need to the content P tags.

Comment: Why `*[class~='hidden'] + h1` and not `.hidden + h1`?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that one a little later too. I've updated my sample. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you are going to hide the content using inline styles:

```
h1 + h1, p[style*="display: none"] + h1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Check **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/qFyUc/